# Привет! Помогите пожалуйста! Хотел сам найти способ решения этой проблемы, но не нашел

Tags: c#, unity3d

(1-й скрипт)
public float num = 100;

(2-й скрипт)
num = 134;

Я хочу поменять значения num из 2-го скрипта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов. Во-первых : Написать в Скрипте (Script1) объявить переменную как `public static float num = 100;` 
А во втором скрипте `ScriptOne.num = 134;` 
Второй способ : в скрипте ScriptOne:

```
 public float num = 100;
```

А во втором скрипте

```
  class Script2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] // Указывается в инспекторе
    GameObject obj; // Объект, на котором Script1

    void Start()
    {
        obj.GetComponent<Script1>().num = 134;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помог!