# UNITY как перенести значение переменной с одного кода в другой в одной сцене

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui, variable

Есть два кода:

Тут есть глобальнаая переменная ***isDeath***, которую к окончании времени выставляю на true

```
if(timerbar.fillAmount <=0){
        isDeath = true;
     }
```

тут ее можно увидеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь хочу использовать ее значение в этом коде (код для одного из спрайтов на той же сцене)

```
if (isDeath)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("allPoints", all);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("correctPoints", good);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
```

только вот не знаю как передать значение той переменной в этот код

Прощу о помощи))

Comment: Недавно был похожий вопрос: [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118594/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Comment: ООО, спасибочки огромное))

Comment: @Methorn а если первый код не на GameObject а на Image, так тоже срабоает?

Comment: Image является игровым объектом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращаешься к объекту, у него к компоненту скрипта и берешь значение: UrGameObject.GetComponent().IsDeath